# Why 'std::make_shared' is always using the global memory allocation even with class overloaded new/delete operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, make-shared

When using `std::make_shared<C>` the class overloaded new/delete operators are not called.

When using `std::shared_ptr<C>`, `std::unique_ptr<C>` & `std::make_unique<C>` the class overloaded new/delete operators are used.

When looking at the documentation it's perfectly correct and well documented.

[cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) explains the behavior:

> `std::make_shared` uses ::new, so if any special behavior has been set up using a class-specific operator new, it will differ from `std::shared_ptr<T>(new T(args...))`.

Below is some pseudo-code to better highlight the behavior:

```
#include <memory>

class C {
 public:
  void* operator new(size_t size) {
    void* p = ::operator new(size);
    std::cout << "C::new() -> " << p << "\n";
    return p;
  }

  void operator delete(void* p) {
    std::cout << "C::delete() -> " << p << "\n";
    ::operator delete(p);
  }
};

std::shared_ptr<C> ptr = std::make_shared<C>();
```

From an external point of view, it seems inconsistent and error prone. Overloading class new/delete operators should always be used.

So, what is the rationale of the behavior?

And, where is the C++ specification detailing the `std::make_shared` behavior?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: They added [`std::allocate_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) for this

Answer (score 12):

> So, what is the rational of the behavior?

The reason this is done is because `make_shared` doesn't just allocate your object, it also allocates the control block of the `shared_ptr`.  To make this as efficient as possible, it calls `new` once and allocates enough storage for the control block and the object in one go.  Otherwise it would have to call `new` twice which doubles the allocation overhead.

If you want to use a custom allocator then you need to use [`std::allocate_shared`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/allocate_shared) and it will use your custom allocator to do a single memory acquisition to create the `shared_ptr`.

---

Another option is to use `std::make_unique` to create a `unique_ptr`, and then use that to initialize the `shared_ptr`.  This works because `unique_ptr` does not have a control block so `std::make_unique` allocates in the form of

```
unique_ptr<T>(new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
```

That would give you

```
std::shared_ptr<C> ptr = std::make_unique<C>();
```

which outputs

```
C::new() -> 0xf34c20
C::delete() -> 0xf34c20
```

Comment: Sometimes C++ just makes you groan with intense pain.

Comment: @einpoklum For the most part it is painless.  This is just another reason to not overload new and delete for your type.  If they really want to they can leverage `unique_ptr` (adding that to the answer in a minute).

Comment: It's painfull for people to need to be aware of the distinction between `make_shared` and `allocate_shared`...

Comment: The alternative with `make_unique` is no better than just using `new` to initialize shared_ptr.

Comment: @SergeyA It has one important advantage, I didn't have to type `new` to get it to do what the OP wanted. I like not having to type `new` :-)

Comment: I can understand this. However, `new` will still hit you when you use it for placement new. Life is not fair.

Answer (score 5):

The immediate reason for this behavior is the fact that `std::make_shared` performs a single allocation to allocate both control block and the object. It has no other option but to use global operator new for this.

Also, I would like to mention that I personally consider ability to overload the new/delete operators for a class one of the most ill-conceived features of C++. A class should not prescribe methods of it's memory allocation. Rather, class allocation should be delegated to particular task at hand, and a well-designed class should behave equally well be it allocated in dynamic storage, automatic storage, in memory mapped file or on a flash card.

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to some discussion about this feature?

Comment: @einpoklum you mean overloading new/delete for a class? I do not have a link, this is my personal opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain why `std::make_shared` doesn't use your class specific `operator new` and `operator delete`. This is just a side note.

If you'd like to use referenced counter pointers with your object and use your class specific allocation/deallocation another option is to use [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_71_0/libs/smart_ptr/doc/html/smart_ptr.html#intrusive_ptr).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/smart_ptr/intrusive_ref_counter.hpp>

class C : public boost::intrusive_ref_counter<C, boost::thread_safe_counter> {
public:
    static void* operator new(size_t size) {
        void* p = ::operator new(size);
        std::cout << "C::new() -> " << p << "\n";
        return p;
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p) {
        std::cout << "C::delete() -> " << p << "\n";
        ::operator delete(p);
    }
};

int main() {
    boost::intrusive_ptr<C> c(new C);
}
```

The drawbacks of `boost::intrusive_ptr` are:

- It is *intrusive*. The class must have the reference counter as one of its members or derive from `boost::intrusive_ref_counter`. You don't necessarily need to change the class definition, a wrapper class with a counter that derives from your class can be used (but that loses class specific allocation/deallocations functions again).
- No weak pointers.

The benefits are:

- `sizeof(boost::intrusive_ptr<T>) == sizeof(T*)`, whereas `sizeof(std::shared_ptr<T>) == 2 * sizeof(T*)`.
- You have a choice of thread safe or unsafe reference counter. For objects that never cross thread boundaries using a thread safe counter is wasteful: atomic increments and decrements are most expensive (as all of atomic read-modify-write operations). `std::shared_ptr<T>` always uses a 2 (two) thread-safe counters in multi-threaded applications. In well designed applications only objects of a few message classes ever cross thread boundaries.
- The reference counter is stored inside your object which is the best case in terms of locality of reference / most cache friendly. `std::make_shared` does that for you as well, but you lose your class specific allocation/deallocation functions.
- Can be assigned to and swapped in wait-free atomic fashion.

Comment: This is a nice answer, but not to OP's question, which is "Why XYZ".... Consider asking a follow-up question about overcoming this restriction, posting your answer there and a comment here pointing people over there. I promise an upvote :-)

Comment: @einpoklum This is a speculative answer with _The other answers explain why... / If you'd like to use referenced pointers..._ caveat. I could post a question and answer it myself, but that is not my style.

Comment: I understand, but other people will likely miss your answer if it's under a "Why" question.

Comment: @einpoklum I understand and thanks for the tip, but I just like sharing when I feel like it.